# Convert Oracles table storage options into SQL Server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

I have the following statement in Oracle and I want to use the same in SQL Server. How would I do that?

```
SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE    
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING   
STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645   
          PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL 
          DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)   
TABLESPACE "CMS_DATA" ;
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to happen; you're talking about the internals of the database, which are different. You need a proper SQL Server DBA to tune to this depth of complexity for you.

Comment: You dont have to specify them. Oracle provides option for user to manage them where as sql server does not.